# How to get rows from two tables on maximum value of particular field

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, groupwise-maximum

I have two tables  that has `date_updated` column.

`TableA` is like below

```
 con_id         date_updated         type     
--------------------------------------------
123              19/06/2018          2
123              15/06/2018          1     
123              01/05/2018          3  
101              06/04/2018          1
101              05/03/2018          2
```

And I have `TableB` that also has the same structure

```
 con_id         date_updated         type     
--------------------------------------------
123              15/05/2018          2  
123              01/05/2018          1  
101              07/06/2018          1
```

The resultant table should have  the data with the recent date

```
 con_id         date_updated         type     
--------------------------------------------
123              19/06/2018          2
101              07/06/2018          1
```

Here the `date_updated` column is `datetime` datatype of sql server.  I tried this by using `group by` and selecting the maximum `date_updated`. But i am not able to include column type in `select` statement. When i used type in `group by` ,the result is not correct as the type is also grouped. How can i query this. Please help

Comment: _Column_, not field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By con_id ORDER BY date_updated DESC) as seq
     FROM
        (SELECT * FROM TableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM TableB) as tblMain) as tbl2
WHERE seq = 1
```

Comment: `as seq` from where?? which table?? you need to add `FROM` there.

Comment: `tblMain` is union of two tables, `tbl2` is tblmain with additional column named seq.
thanks I edited it

Answer (score 1):

One method:

```
WITH A AS(
    SELECT TOP 1 con_id,
                 date_updated,
                 type
    FROM TableA
    ORDER BY date_updated DESC),
B AS(
    SELECT TOP 1 con_id,
                 date_updated,
                 type
    FROM TableB
    ORDER BY date_updated DESC),
U AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM B)
SELECT *
FROM U;
```

The 2 CTE's at the top get your most recent rows from the tables, and then the end statement unions them together.

For the benefit of the person who says this doesn't work:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE tablea (con_id int, date_updated date, [type] tinyint);
CREATE TABLE tableb (con_id int, date_updated date, [type] tinyint);
GO

INSERT INTO tablea 
VALUES
(123,'19/06/2018',2),
(123,'15/06/2018',1),     
(123,'01/05/2018',3),  
(101,'06/04/2018',1),
(101,'05/03/2018',2); 

INSERT INTO tableb
VALUES
(123,'15/05/2018',2),  
(123,'01/05/2018',1), 
(101,'07/06/2018',1);
GO
WITH A AS(
    SELECT TOP 1 con_id,
                 date_updated,
                 [type]
    FROM TableA
    ORDER BY date_updated DESC),
B AS(
    SELECT TOP 1 con_id,
                 date_updated,
                 [type]
    FROM TableB
    ORDER BY date_updated DESC),
U AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM B)
SELECT *
FROM U;

GO
DROP TABLE tablea;
DROP TABLE tableb;
```

This returns the dataset:

```
con_id      date_updated type
----------- ------------ ----
123         2018-06-19   2
101         2018-06-07   1
```

Which is identical to the OP's data:

```
 con_id         date_updated         type     
--------------------------------------------
123              19/06/2018          2
101              07/06/2018          1
```

Comment: thanking you for you answer. But i have to join this select statement with another table using con_id. Starting with WITH is it possible to join query.

Comment: Yes, put the `UNION` query inside another CTE.

Comment: This query is not giving the desried result. You might wanna dry run it with some data. You get the TOP of the table for `date_updated` column but missing the grouping based on `con_id`.

Comment: @AmithKumar that isn't the OP's sample data.

Comment: Yes but OP's said he needs to group by `con_id`. If there are more than two `con_id` or both tables has latest for same `con_id`, provided query ignores the other `con_id`s.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
WITH combined 
     AS( 
select * FROM tableA 
UNION 
select * FROM tableB) 

SELECT t1.con_id, 
       t1.date_updated, 
       t1.type 
FROM  ( 
                SELECT   con_id, 
                         date_updated, 
                         type, 
                         row_number() OVER(partition BY con_id ORDER BY date_updated DESC) AS rownumber
                FROM     combined) t1 
WHERE  rownumber = 1;
```

Comment: That won't work, an `ORDER BY` has to be after all the `UNION`'s. For example, try `SELECT 1 AS i ORDER BY i UNION SELECT 2 AS i ORDER BY i;`. You'll get a syntax error.

Comment: Yup totally missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using window functions:

```
declare @TableA table (con_id int, date_updated date, [type] int)
declare @TableB table (con_id int, date_updated date, [type] int)

insert into @TableA values
  (123, '2018-06-19', 2)
, (123, '2018-06-15', 1)     
, (123, '2018-05-01', 3)  
, (101, '2018-04-06', 1)
, (101, '2018-03-05', 2) 

insert into @TableB values
  (123, '2018-05-15', 2)  
, (123, '2018-05-01', 1)  
, (101, '2018-06-07', 1)

select distinct con_id
    , first_value(date_updated) over (partition by con_id order by con_id, date_updated desc) as con_id
    , first_value([type]) over (partition by con_id order by con_id, date_updated desc) as [type]
from
(Select * from @TableA UNION Select * from @TableB) x
```